# TextView.setText disables CheckBox's default animation

Tags: android, textview, android-checkbox

I have a `GridView with CheckBoxes` and every time the user clicks a CheckBox I call `TextView.setText()`, Somehow calling `setText()` disables the default animation Android gives to Check Boxes. why does it happen?

**EDIT:**
this is my my listener:

```
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    checkedPositions.add(position + 1);
                } else {
                    checkedPositions.remove(new Integer(position + 1));
                }
                //removing this line brings back the animation
                TextView.setText("some text");
            }
        });
```

Comment: There is no animation for checkboxes in android. Can you please provide more details with your code?

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply. I'm talking about this animation : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFA9Ig6ZXQQ

Comment: Yeah, I checked it now. But the video title says that it's lollipop style. And that animation depends on your styles.xml code What is written there? Can you post styles.xml?

Comment: I don't have anything related in my styles.xml , this animation appears by default on devices running lollipop and sadly calling setText() in my "setOnCheckedChangeListener" disables it

Comment: Yes, I know. I just wanted to check what was written in styles.xml because you might use holo theme or something which doesn't have animation for checkboxes. This animation is added in lollipop I think. So you need to use Theme.DeviceDefault in your parent theme. But that animation will only work on lollipop devices. Theme.DeviceDefault will let the theme of your app be like the theme in the user's system apps like the settings. If you already had animation before settingText of a TextView, then I'm sorry, it's a weird problem I don't know how to fix. Try to post some xml code or something.

Comment: What kind of listener do you use on your check box? If you return false it means the event is consumed and that may affect the animation, depending how its handled. the same thing if you programmatically change the check box in that listener.

Comment: Hi , Nick thanks for your reply , I'm not sure I understood you 100% , I posted my listener

Comment: Not sure if it was a typo, but if it wan't, it's bad practice to have variables start with an uppercase letter. I would change `TextView` to `textView`. Even if it doesn't fix it, it will make your code more readable and it will follow convention better.